# Настройка постоянных ссылок для темы

Tags: wordpress

Установлена тема DFD Native для wordpress, проблема с `Постоянными ссылками`.
Сейчас в Настройках выбрана такая опция для постоянных ссылок "Постоянные ссылки" > "День и название". Все ссылки работают, кроме ссылки `http://site.com/portfolio`, т.е. при открытии этой страницы портфолио, загружается архивный шаблон.
Шаблон имеется ввиду этот `Portfolio page template`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А если поменять постоянные ссылки на "Постоянные ссылки" > "Цифры", то проблема отпадает, страница портфолио работает, загружается нужный шаблон для портфолио, но у записей блога появляется такой урл: `http://site.com/archives/24418`, что не совсем читабельно.

Подскажите, как решить данную проблему?
т.е. почему при смене опции постоянных ссылок на "Цифры" шаблон портфолио нормально загружается, а при смене на "День и название" шаблон портфолио не загружается?

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить? т.е. нужно чтобы была опция постоянных ссылок `"Постоянные ссылки" > "День и название"` и работал шаблон портфолио

Comment: решил данную проблему, нужно было в настройках темы для портфолио прописать слаг /portfolio, и перезагрузить постоянные ссылки